# QObject::deleteLater() when pointer is zero

Tags: qt, pointers, qt4

Is it safe calling QObject::deleteLater() when pointer equals 0? I googled it and searched in documentation, but I didn't find any helpful information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not be able / should not do any call to a function of a 0 pointer.
It should be treated as a delete operation but it's a function of the object itself, so no object no function.

Comment: I'm blunted :( I can just check that pointer equals 0. Thank you  :)

Comment: deleteLater() does: QCoreApplication::postEvent(this, new QEvent(QEvent::DeferredDelete)); which in turn prints a warning "unexpected null receiver". So technically it doesn't crash, but as there is no guarantee given by the API, it's wrong to rely on that.

Comment: In general, calling functions on null pointer is valid. In practice, when you dereference the null pointer this, it will crash. If you do thing like: `if(this==NULL) return;` then calling this method on null pointer is safe - comparing pointers is not dereferencing. In Qt, PostEvent to null receiver does not crash, so deleteLater will only throw a warning. It does not dereference `this`. pointer. You can also read more about `__thiscall`

Comment: In a sense it is good that `deleteLater()` does **not** cause a crash if you call it on a nullptr: it is a replacement for `delete` and you **can** `delete somepointer` without having to worry about `somepointer` being null (or not)